# Copy data from CSV file based on AWS S3 bucket to Postgresql with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pipeline

I am trying to create my first pipeline.

So my task is to create a pipeline with python, which purpose is to upload CSV file from a local system to AWS S3 Bucket.

After that I need to copy the data from this CSV file into  PostgreSQL table. I checked AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import ). I follow the instructions but still get an error when i try to run the code from the tutorial in my python environment.

The Questions: is it possible to achieve it with python?
Could someone share a little bit knowlege and python code how he do it?

Comment: Share the CSV, query you used and what error did you get if possible.

Comment: The CSV is basic with 5 columns: CustomerID ,Gender, Age,income,spending_score          I Tried something like  that:  SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'MY_table',
   '', 
   '(format csv)',
   :'s3_uri'
);
I saw that in AWS Tutorial. The errors  - that i have problem with transaction and syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: Okay, and you type the query yourself in python. You escaped the URI properly? (I believe it has the following form: s3://bucket-name/path/object.txt, which means you have to escape slashes I guess prior to sending it).